# Is there a video format where the coloured video is three times the size of its grayscale version?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Is there a video format in which the colored video is three times the size of its grayscale version. Say the grayscale video is of 30MB, is there any video format where it's colored version is 90MB. Because ideally the colored image should be roughly three times the size of its grayscale version. As grayscale contains a single array whereas colored images are made of three arrays.

However when I convert a colored MP4 or AVI videos into their grayscale versions, there is very much of a reduction in memory size. I wanted a video format in which there is at least 50% or more reduction in data.

Answer (score 1):

An uncompressed video stream will indeed have three time the size for color compared to greyscale.

However, video compression typically treats the color component (hue and saturation, chrominance, or whatever is used) and the intensity (luminosity, brightness, or whatever is used) differently. The color component is typically compressed much more strongly, because our eyes are less sensitive to degradation in the quality of the color reproduction.

For example, JPEG compression (it's for photos, not video, but the same applies there) typically has 1/2 or 1/4 the number of samples for chrominance than for brightness. See [the description of this on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Color_space_transformation) for more details.

Thus, it is normal and expected that there is not a 1:3 ratio in the size of compressed video stream for greyscale vs RGB video.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, do you know of any video format where even after the compression, the grayscale video is significantly less in size than the colored video? It will be of great help.

Comment: @AnkurSingh: No, I don't. Video tends to be compressed well, because otherwise it is too large to do anything with. And if you compress it well, then color information takes up a small portion of the total information. Uncompressed video is the only place where you have the 1:3 ratio, that I know of.